# Is there a way to fetch individual subdirectories instead of entire git repo?

Tags: git, github, repository, repo, git-fetch

I'm working on a project where I would like to work on separate subdirectory without fetching the entire repo.

As an example, `project_repo` has the structure:

```
project_repo/
  mainProgram/
  pluginA/
  pluginB/
```

I will work on `pluginA` on my local machine while someone else is working on `pluginB`.

To do so I could just clone the entire repo into the **.../plugins/** folder on my pc, but that will lead to errors with the program because I'm trying to run `pluginB` which **isn't ready yet** and also `mainProgram` which **is not a plugin**.

**Is it possible to bring a single subdirectory to my local machine?** My last resource would be to work on separate repos for each plugin, but I'm working with +180 plugins and would be exponentially harder to track, coordinate and add to the original project repo (which don't know if it's possible).

Comment: In git, a commit is a snapshot of _the entire repo_. So even if you shallow clone one commit, you'll get all the files and directories in that commit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+directory

Comment: @evolutionxbox Filters help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/7976758